# Python extract imports and download them with pip

Tags: python, pip

I want to get a list from all imports of a (selfwritten) module and fetch them via PIP programmatically. Is there a way to do this?

I thought of analysing the file via open(model.py) extract the import statements and then subprocess PIP, but is there a better way?

EDIT:
This helps out with PIP: 
http://blog.ducky.io/python/2013/08/22/calling-pip-programmatically/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the answer from Rob, I came to the following solution:

```
def satisfy_dependencies(path_to_dir):
    # Generate requirements.txt using pipreqs and then use pip to fetch the requirements
    proc = Popen(["pipreqs", path_to_dir, "--savepath", os.path.join(path_to_dir, "requirements.txt"), "--force"])

    while proc.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.1)

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path_to_dir, "requirements.txt")):
        pip = Popen(["pip", "install", "-r", os.path.join(path_to_dir, "requirements.txt")])

        while pip.poll() is None:
            time.sleep(0.1)

        os.remove(os.path.join(path_to_dir, "requirements.txt"))
```

Much sub processing but did the job in my case.
I'll be back.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options that I know of.

1. [pigar](https://github.com/damnever/pigar)
2. [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

Both will pull imports from your project and give you a requirements.txt file that you can use with pip.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it in a try/except condition.

something like:

```
import pip

while True:
    try:
        import mymodule
        break
    except ImportError as e:
        dependency = str(e).split(" ")[-1]
        if dependency == 'mymodule':
            break
        pip.main(['install', dependency])
```

my thinking:

1. try to import - if you don't have the dependencies installed you should raise an ImportError
2. if it fails the last word of the error message should be the name of the module you need, install it using pip as suggested in the page you linked.
3. you could also get an ImportError if your module doesn't exist - so we test for that and break

I can imagine a problem, depending on the pip module (which I haven't used) if a module has a different import name to pip name, eg MySQLdb, which is installed via $pip install MySQL-python